# in terminal utilizing vi command , somehow changed the keyboard so that upon pressing a character on the keyboard does not output the proper value

Tags: linux, terminal, keyboard-layout, vi

while in terminal . utilizing and learning basic Linux commands and was covering the usage of the vi command when it became apparent that something was different than the screen that i was taking instruction from. i tried to clear quit or exit and to no avail it would not allow me to anything and some series and combinations of pushed keys while trying to exit the mode i was in had the resultant effect of when certain keys were pushed , they no longer had the predetermined output ..ie when i push the l key , it would output a 3 instead .. approx. 12 keys seem to be effected in this way and even after rebooting and re entering the terminal did not reset it to traditional output values .. any assistance would be greatly appreciated .. correct me if i am wrong but do i now have to reinstall the entire distro to correct the problem .. i do want to up grade to uma as i have an older version of cinnamon anyway .. but pleases instruct me on the correction if there is one and ill upgrade to a newer version afterwards ..

Comment: Is this a laptop? Could you have simply enabled numlock?

Comment: i don't believe so would that have that drastic an effect on the output of pushed character like now the l character is a 3 the k is a 4  m is a 9 ect and then on the other side of the keyboard the keys when depressed are the right values . i was playing around with the vi command ayt the time when this happened if that helps at all

Comment: and yes as a matter of fact it was a laptop

Comment: and yes that did seem to solve the problem /.. could you provide a little context for better understanding ?

Comment: What's to say? It's typical behaviour for a laptop that NumLock changes the default action of a block of keys. If you look on the key caps you may even find the alternate characters printed

Comment: good enough .. thanks again

Comment: mine shows ins and num lk

Comment: Look at the keyboard on your laptop. You will probably see the keys that were behaving strangely have numbers on them, probably in a different color. When you press the numlock button, these keys behave as though they were a numerical keypad.

Comment: they do yes .. and the whole thing comes together.. i see it now .. for all the years of using a keyboard i never gave much thought to the underlying characters and functions of the secondary highlighted functions below  .. might just search out a quick tutorial on this subject of keyboards and all its functions to see what else i don't know about something i took for granted . as now that i look harder at the keyboard..  I'm thinking that there maybe a few things i see I really have no clue about... greatly appreciated as its a stark reminder about taking things for granted ..